# Relative difficulty between leading zero counting and addition

Tags: integrated-circuit, circuit-design, adder

Consider a 32-bit or 64-bit ALU that must implement both *count leading zeros* and *integer addition*, with low latency (say a few cycles), implemented on a modern high frequency logic process.

Which is generally more complex, a fast adder or a fast leading zero count?

Comment: hm, what do you need "count leading zeros" for?

Comment: What *sort* of leading zeros do you want to count?  Binary?  Hex?  BCD?  Decimal?  And does the way the information is *stored* match the way you want to count it?   Binary zeroes are at least straightforward, but counting decimal zeros in a base 2 value is a bit more complex.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - binary. I.e., like the `clz` instruction available in most modern ISAs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - it's a common instruction on modern CPU ISAs, and I was in a discussion where there was a claim made that it was "no harder than an adder", and I wanted to check it. In particular, modern Intel x86 chips go through the bother of implementing their integer SIMD `clz` instruction on the floating unit, which is quite unusual (the only other integer stuff that follows that pattern is integer mul, which is not surprising considering the cost of fast, wide multipliers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 64-bit leading zero counter, what you'd need is at most a 6-NOR-deep combinatorial chain plus one XOR (or equivalent) ("is the first bit zero, and the second bit one", "are the previous bits zero, using the result from the previous step") and 6 bit LUT.

That's very little.

A trivial ripple-block carry lookahead adder with 64 bit operands needs six stages, so it might be minimally faster, which is also very little.

In other words: I can't give you a definite answer; actual fast implementations will depend on the standard blocks that the hardware designer can employ: for example, on a modern high-performance FPGA, you'd either just use an arithmetic block (and not care about the design), or build it from 6-LUTs; so, these combinatorial considerations have no relevance to FPGA design. On an ASIC of an actual silicon CPU, neither components will be close to being the most complex things to do during a single clock cycle, and thus, more combinatorial steps in favor of e.g. lower routing overhead or lower switching probability might be favored.

Comment: Just a thought that occurred to me while reading the question and your answer. The OP didn't mentioned an FPGA, so far as I can tell. So I was thinking ASIC when reading the OP.

Comment: @jonk indeed, I had ASIC in mind when I wrote this answer. But the truth is, students implementing ALUs are likely to do it in pure simulation or FPGAs...

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of ASICs. @jonk